# Files created with openFileOutput method are removed when the app is updated

Tags: android, data-storage

I'm saving some user data in the internal storage using the openFileOutput method in Context class.
The problem is that when I update the app all these files are removed. Is there any way to avoid these files to be removed?

Regads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not removed when your app is updated. They will be removed when your app is uninstalled. Perhaps you are uninstalling and reinstalling your app instead of doing an in-place upgrade.